# Applet remote debugging

Tags: java, eclipse, applet, remote-debugging

I've installed Java Plugin 11.25.2.18 (JRE 1.8.0_25-b18) and I'm not able to debug an applet I've developed. Before JRE 1.8.0_25-b18 I was able to debug applets. I've configured debug with the next options:

```
-Djava.compiler=NONE -Xnoagent -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=2502,server=y,suspend=n
```

Then in eclipse I create a remote debug configuration as:

```
Connection type: Standard (Socket Attach)
Host: localhost
Port: 2502
```

This is the error message eclipse returns:

[image: error message]

Of course the browser and eclipse are runing in the same machine.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason why you do not start the Applet in Debug mode directly and local from Eclipse? Or why do you need to debug it remotely?

Comment: My web application uses this applet, so the applet is going to run in the JVM plugin that use the browser, and for that reason, I want to debug remotely (in the JVM plugin).